# Return updated values from sequelize raw query

Tags: postgresql, sequelize.js

I have an operation that uses a raw query to update the database, i'd like to get the rows affected by the query as the output. Is this possible?

```
const op = (replacements, pgdb) { 
  const query = q(replacements);
  const args = [query, { replacements, type: Sequelize.QueryTypes.UPDATE, raw: true }];
  const results = await pgdb.query(...args);
  console.log(results);
  return results;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Postgresql can return records with `RETURNING`.

```
UPDATE T
SET ...
WHERE ...
RETURNING *
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. I'm using Sequelize with a PostgreSQL database. My specs are as follows:

> "pg": "^7.12.1"
>
> "sequelize": "^5.21.2"
>
> "sequelize-cli": "^5.5.1"

I ran an update query in the following code block:

```
const query = `UPDATE bookings b
    SET "isPaid" = :isPaid,
        "paymentType" = :paymentType
    FROM trips t,
         requests r
    WHERE "b"."tripId" = t.id
      AND r.id = "t"."requestId"
      AND r.id = :requestId
      AND "r"."userId" = :userId
    RETURNING b.id, "isPaid", "paymentType"`;

    return db.sequelize.query(
      query, {
        replacements: {
          isPaid, paymentType, requestId, userId
        }
      }
    );
```

I logged the result:

```
console.log('resultFromQuery', resultFromQuery);
```

and got the following:

```
resultFromQuery [
  [
    { id: 7, isPaid: true, paymentType: 'paypal' },
    { id: 8, isPaid: true, paymentType: 'paypal' }
  ],
  Result {
    command: 'UPDATE',
    rowCount: 2,
    oid: null,
    rows: [ [Object], [Object] ],
    fields: [ [Field], [Field], [Field] ],
    _parsers: [ [Function: parser], [Function: parser], [Function: parser] ],
    _types: TypeOverrides { _types: [Object], text: {}, binary: {} },
    RowCtor: null,
    rowAsArray: false
  }
]
```

I was then able to get the rowCount as follows:

```
console.log('resultFromQuery', resultFromQuery[1].rowCount);
```

I was also able to get the updated rows themselves as follows (you can select the entire row like you did with **'*'** or specify the fields you want):

```
console.log('resultFromQuery', resultFromQuery[0]);
```